# Is it true that the intersection of a sequence $K_1 \supset K_2 \supset K_3 \dotsm$ of connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is also connected?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

I have got one counterexample for this :
Consider the family {***D***} of closed discs centered at zero having radius $1+1/n$, i.e. disc $D_1$ has radius $1+1=2$, $D_2$ has radius $1+1/2=1.5$, and so on. Now consider the family {***D'***} of sets of the form $D_i-\{(0,y)\mid -1 \leq y \leq 1 \}$. Each of these sets is connected but their arbitrary intersection is not. Is this example is correct ? If not please provide another one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove that $\bigcap_{k = 1}^\infty C_k$ is also compact and connected.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466743/prove-that-bigcap-k-1-infty-c-k-is-also-compact-and-connected)

Comment: @Surb Compactness is not assumed here...

Comment: @DavidMitra this is correct but the link in question is a duplicate of another link that does not deal with compactness

Comment: Your example seems to be OK.

Comment: This question does not deal with compactness. example which I have mentioned have sets of the form neither open nor close. and since we are considering usual topology of R2, only closed and bounded sets can be considered as compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another example involving closed (but not bounded) sets. Let $A_n = (-1, 1) \times (-n, n)$. Let $B_n = \mathbb R^2 - A_n$. Each $B_n$ is connected. We have
$$
\bigcap_n B_n = ((-\infty, -1] \times \mathbb R) \cup ([1, \infty) \times \mathbb R).
$$

Thus, $\bigcap_n B_n$ is disconnected.